# How to create this specific interface type in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create this interface type: https://prnt.sc/oqprzp

My knowledge in programming is not the best and i also didn´t use python before only a little bit of javascript. I would be happy about any advice how to create the whole interface type and not the calculation in it. 
Thank you very much for your help.
(I´m from germany and thats why there are some german words into the code. 
I hope that they don´t confuse to hard.)

I have tried to look up the basics and something of this stuff but i didn´t find something that could help me here. I only did the buttons yet as u can see in the following code and they are working as they should. I´m also not sure how i can do them into the right under corner like in my screenshot.

```
from tkinter import *

#Erstellung des GUI
GUI = Tk()
GUI.title("GUI - Querschnittswerte berechnen eines Trapezes")
GUI.geometry("1000x600")

#Erstellung der Buttons
class Buttons:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.calculateButton = Button(frame, text = "Querschnittswerte berechnen", command=self.printMessage)
        self.calculateButton.pack(side=LEFT)



        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Zusammenfassung/Drucken", command=self.printMessage)
        self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)



        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Beenden", command=frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)



    def printMessage(self):
        print("Wird ausgeführt... Fehler entstanden und kann dadurch nicht ausgeführt werden.")


b = Buttons(GUI)
GUI.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no special technique, other than to be methodical and to analyze the layout to see if you can spot some patterns.

For example, I see some very clear patterns:

1. you have a row of buttons across the bottom
2. above the buttons, the UI is divided into a left and right half
3. the left half is divided into two equal sections
4. the right half is a notebook with two tabs
5. each tab contains a series of input fields arranged in a grid.

### Getting started

I would start by creating frames for each of the sections. During initial development I would give them distinctive colors so that they are easy to visualize, and also temporarily give empty frames a size so that they are visible.

Also, I would create either a function or class to represent each section to better organize the code.

Because of the relatively simple layout of the highest level structures, `pack` is probably the right tool for laying them out.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("800x400")

        left = self.create_left(self.root)
        right = self.create_right(self.root)
        buttons = self.create_buttons(self.root)

        buttons.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        left.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        right.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

    def create_left(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, background="bisque", height=200)

        return frame

    def create_right(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, background="yellow", height=200)

        return frame

    def create_buttons(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, background="orange", height=40)

        return frame

example = Example()
tk.mainloop()
```

With that, you can run the program and visualize the main sections. You can also verify that the sections behave properly when you resize the window.

[image: screenshot of basic layout]

### Refining the UI

Next, repeat this process for each section. For example, add a notebook to the right section by modifying `create_right` to look like this:

```
def create_right(self, master):
    frame = tk.Frame(master, background="yellow", height=200)

    self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(frame)
    self.notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    self.tab1 = tk.Frame(self.notebook, background="lightblue")
    self.tab2 = tk.Frame(self.notebook, background="yellow")

    self.notebook.add(self.tab1, text="Eingabe der Profildaten")
    self.notebook.add(self.tab2, text="Querschnittswerte des Profils")

    return frame
```

When you run the program, some proportions will change since you're adding more widgets. Don't worry, when you add widgets to the left and bottom, everything will continue to fit.

[image: screenshot including notebook tabs]

Now, tackle the left side using the same technique. Modify `create_left` to look like the following. While normally I would use `pack` here, too, I'll use grid in this example just to prove that you can mix and match `grid` and `pack` in different sections.

```
def create_left(self, master):
    frame = tk.Frame(master, background="bisque", height=200)

    lf1 = tk.LabelFrame(frame, borderwidth=2, relief="groove",
                         text="Profildarstellung")
    lf2 = tk.LabelFrame(frame, borderwidth=2, relief="groove",
                         text="Koordinatensystem im Schwerpunkt",)

    lf1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)
    lf2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

    frame.grid_rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    return frame
```

[image: screenshot with left label frames]

### Using classes

Instead of creating functions, you could instead use classes. If the class inherits from `Frame`, you can treat the class just like any other tkinter widget with respect to laying it out with other widgets. For example, instead of calling `create_buttons`, you can instantiate a class:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        buttons = Buttons(self.root)
        buttons.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        ...
```

Then, create a class that inherits from some other widget so that it can be placed in the UI like any other widget. This is what the `Frame` widget is designed for.

```
class Buttons(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, background="orange")

        self.calculateButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Querschnittswerte berechnen")
        self.printButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Zusammenfassung/Drucken")
        self.quitButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Beenden")

        self.quitButton.pack(side="right", padx=4, pady=4)
        self.printButton.pack(side="right", padx=4, pady=4)
        self.calculateButton.pack(side="right", padx=4, pady=4)
```

[image: screenshot including buttons]

### Final steps

Continue building up your GUI one section at a time, testing along the way to make sure the layout stays correct as you resize the window. Once you have all of the pieces, you can go back in and remove the colors and hard-coded frame sizes to give your UI a more polished look.

[image: final screenshot]

Comment: @Bryan Oaklay Thank you for your fast answer but i tried a lot today and couldn´t fix some problems with it. I could only create: http://prntscr.com/oqxuos.

Comment: @Bryan Oaklay I have got errors with ttk and also that i couldn´t declare those other steps like left, right frame and the buttons. I understand the declaration behind those steps but i´m not sure what i have to exactly do to fix it. Maybe u can give me some more tips why that doesn´t work if i use that code of yours. http://prntscr.com/oqxxo5 (here some of that errors)

Comment: @Freez: don't copy my code. Copy the _concepts_. My code works -- those are real screeenshots from the actual code in the answer -- but the point isn't the code, the point is the _technique_.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah, i didn´t really wanted to just copy it and i understand your steps behind it but my knowledge is not the best in python and i don´t even understand why the systems gets errors with ttk in it. I tried some points to do them like in my example for the buttons but they wont show up and i don´t get why even if i try to declare that class it will make errors. ^^

Comment: @Freez: my apologies. I added some last minute changes to the code which prevented it from working. I've updated the code and double-checked that it all works.

Comment: @BryanOakley You don´t have to apologize you helped me a lot until now.^^ I´m still not sure why the buttons don´t show even if i only use your code. It is nearly the same like mine. Do i have to interpret the class Buttons? like in mine b=Buttons(GUI)?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the buttons with `pack(side=LEFT)`, which is going to push the buttons to the left of their master element. Changing `LEFT` to `RIGHT` and adjusting the order in which the buttons are packed should solve the issue of getting the buttons to the right side.